# Displaying HTML From an email on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to display a html email on a html page. Technically I can do it but security is a concern, it's possible an attacker could form malicious code and put into a html email.

I've tried using the Microsoft XSS library to sanitize the html but it strips out so much it basically not worth it.

I'm wondering if there's a better solution with iframes or something. eg, is there a way to secure data within an iframe?

GMail seems to display html emails, they must have a good html sanitizer.

Comment: Not sure I understand. HTML in an email can't really do anything malicious on its own. I suppose someone could try to meta refresh, but that shouldn't work as there's no `head` element in an HTML-email body. Most email clients will happily display HTML emails without any worries about security. Web-based mail clients probably *do* sanitize to a certain degree, but I'm not sure how much of that is strictly security-related.

Comment: What's there not to understand? You can write any html into a email, theoretically you can write malicious javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic options are:

1. sanitize the HTML (use a whitelist approach, for safety)
2. use an iframe with a src on a different domain, or with the html5 `sandbox` attribute

Both can be done effectively and there are lots of variations in the detail.

Regarding sanitizing so much it wasn't worth it: good libraries like https://github.com/guardian/html-janitor/ (javascript) and https://github.com/jsocol/bleach (python) have the ability to customize the whitelist. It depends if you're just trying to present typical user-generated HTML emails with basic formatting or if you're trying to display fully "designed" newsletters with lots of images, tables, etc. If just the former, in some quick experimenting with bleach I was able to make most emails look good by simply adding `br` and `div` to the list of approved tags, so the whitespace didn't get wiped.